# Ajax post/gets (forms/links) submits multiple times in jQuery UI tabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-ui

I've implemented jQuery UI tabs in an Rails app, and I get an error: 
When i submit a ajax form or link, it gets submitted multiple times. 
As seen in this Doom console output: 
DELETE http://localhost:3000/innmeldings/101 404 (Not Found) 
DELETE http://localhost:3000/innmeldings/101 404 (Not Found) 
The more times i switch betweens the tabs, the more times the ajax 
link submits. I have googled it, but not found anything, which makes 
me believe this is not a common error in the JQuery UI tabs. 
Any idea what I do wrong?

I uses rails 3.05. I've tried different versions of jQuery og jQuery Ui:

```
class InnmeldingsController < ApplicationController 
  respond_to :js, :html 

  def destroy 
    @innmelding = Innmelding.find(params[:id]) 
    @innmelding.destroy 
    @innmeldings = Innmelding.all 
    respond_with( @innmeldings, :layout => !request.xhr? ) 
  end 

  def list 
    @innmeldings = Innmelding.all 
    respond_to do |format| 
      format.html # index.html.erb 
      format.xml  { render :xml => @innmeldings } 
      format.js 
    end 
  end
```

list.html.erb:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', innmelding, :remote => true, :id => "reload", :method => :delete %></td>
```

application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $( "#nav" ).tabs(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution (thanks to William who got me on the track). By default Rails loads the js files by ajax calls. Solution: Hiding the js files in application.html.erb from other then needed controllers.

In my controller simply:

```
  def index
    @vis_js = 1
  end
```

and application.html.erb:

```
  <% if defined?(@vis_js)%>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'event_calendar', :cache => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js", "jquery.validate.js", "jquery.ui.datepicker-no", :cache => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'rails', :cache => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', :cache => true %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check you're not binding events (e.g. clicks) multiple times. This would occur when you load the same JavaScript files multiple times as you load the tab content via AJAX without caching the content (i.e. with the option `cache: false`, which is default).

Comment: Thanks! Setting cache: true fixed it!

Comment: Only partially solved: When I have a page loaded with ajax in to tabs, the click function is submitted to times after I have been in both tabs. Eventually it looks like the javascript file is cached for each tab, but loaded again when i hit a ajax call in another tab.Is there a way of preventing the javascript file from loading again? Other solutions?

Comment: Why don't you check whether or not the tab content *actually* got reloaded, e.g. with Firebug or Safari's developer tools?

Comment: I had a similar issue that I solved by, rather than including `application.js` (which includes all other javascript files in the `app/assets/javascripts/` tree by default), I individually specified the js files I needed. I found that including `application.js` wound up including the jQuery library multiple times (as shown by inspecting the page load request and seeing which resources were retrieved from the server). Because jQuery was loaded multiple times, all my `remote => true` forms got jQuery events bound to them multiple times. I might be doing something wrong, but this fixed it for me.